Why doesn't Bootstrap forms validation work inside a select field when using the Select2 library?
I have this form below, and I'm using Bootstrap forms validation inside a select input field. I'm also using the Select2 library to search for a specific option from the options list. I'm using the class (js-example-basic-single) to make Select2 work. However, when I use it, and upon clicking the submit button, validation works for all form fields except inside the select field. When I remove this class (js-example-basic-single) from the select input field, validation works normally inside the select field. I don't know the reason for this and I need assistance.


// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(() => {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip01" class="form-label">First name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" value="Mark" required>
    <div class="valid-tooltip">
      Looks good!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip02" value="Otto" required>
    <div class="valid-tooltip">
      Looks good!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltipUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
    <div class="input-group has-validation">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltipUsername" aria-describedby="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend" required>
      <div class="invalid-tooltip">
        Please choose a unique and valid username.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip03" class="form-label">City</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip03" required>
    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
      Please provide a valid city.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip04" class="form-label">State</label>
    <select class="form-control select_acount js-example-basic-single" id="validationTooltip01"required>
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">1</option>
<option value="4">1</option>
<option value="5">1</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip05" class="form-label">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip05" required>
    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
      Please provide a valid zip.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </div>
</form>




The problem is that Select2 is replacing the select element with its own markup. You would need to tell the validator validate the replaced markup, not the original select element.

@disinfor can you edit your solution in  my code?

Does this answer your question? Bootstrap and Select2 form validation
